# Add hours to UTC dateTime

Tags: php, date, datetime

I am sure the answer is right in front of me, but I have a UTC dateTime that looks like this:

```
2014-01-02 04:02:58
```

All I want to do is add some hours to that.

How can I achieve this in PHP?  Further, how would I add days to it if I wanted to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `DateTime()`. Unlike `date()`/`strtotime()` it is timezone and daylight savings time friendly.

```
// PHP 5.2+
$dt = new DateTime('2014-01-02 04:02:58');
$dt->modify('+2 hours');
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$dt->modify('+2 days');
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

[See it in action](http://3v4l.org/knm7u)

Or

```
// PHP 5.3+
$dt = new DateTime('2014-01-02 04:02:58');
$dt->add(new DateInterval('PT2H'));
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$dt->add(new DateInterval('P2D'));
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

[See it in action](http://3v4l.org/Kv1Gl)

Or

```
// PHP 5.4+
echo (new DateTime('2014-01-02 04:02:58'))->add(new DateInterval('PT2H'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

[See it in action](http://3v4l.org/mDK2c)

Reference:

- [`DateTime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)
- [`DateInterval()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php)

Comment: Not saying this is wrong, but I am using Laravel and I am getting an error with this code for some reason.

Comment: Ahh, it's because of the Blade templating system on it.  If you use php tags, it will work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `strtotime()` try like this :

```
echo $new_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime( "2014-01-02 04:02:58".'+3 hours'));
```

Comment: @SuperScript There is a one-liner above that is timezone and daylight savings time friendly